# How to secure my Spring Boot API

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

I have Spring Boot API and a React.js/Redux Frontend.

I want to secure all POST routes plus some GET routes. Only one GET route should be open.

What I did so far is using an access_token (Spring Security). But since there is no login (there are no users for this API) the access_token needs to be static in the Frontend - which is unsecure.

So where can I put the access_token so that the client can access but no one else?

Comment: By the sounds of it you want to make sure that only your front end can make use of your API? CORS will go a long way to achieve this. This will only work in browsers though

Comment: CORS is a good way to handle that - but if someone uses a RestClient (which is hiding the origin) he can still manipulate the data.
So for production i guess its the best to not deploy these routes somehow right?

Comment: Yup, if you cannot guarantee that users will only use a browser that approach will not work. The problem you are facing is that there is no way to exchange auth information without the user being able to see it. You could have a simple environment variable to indicate whether you are running in production and disable POST endpoints based on some logic using an Interceptor: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html